# Magento: How to hide the default store view code from url

Tags: magento-1.9, url, store-view

I tried to install the extension [magento-store-code-master](https://github.com/Knectar/Magento-Store-Codes), 
but nothing happened to me. Can anyone give me more detailed instruction for installation? appreciated!

I followed the instruction to copy the app directory to my root directory home/public_html, but nothing happen?

Answer (score 0):

Have you flushed the cache? Can you see this module on the module list under System --> Configuration --> Advanced ?

Comment: Thank you Jimmy, Sorry, No I can't see this module on the module list, what is the name of this module?

Comment: Thanks Jimmy, it works now.  I uploaded the zip file and extracted it, it did not work this way, I just uploaded file by file, it works now. Thanks.